# Why is React Native aspectRatio ignored on video elements?

Tags: react-native, expo

Please have a look at this snack:

https://snack.expo.io/@yolpsoftware/groaning-nachos

When you run it in web (separate window) and then resize the window a bit, you'll notice some strange behavior:

- <strike>This might have been an error in Expo Snack. When I reloaded the window, the behavior disappeared. So the following is not relevant anymore: When the window is big enough for the two videos to fit in, their parents get a height of `0`, so they are rendered on top of each other. As soon as you make the window smaller, this behavior disappears.</strike>
- Even though both the `<Video>` and their direct parents have `width: 100%` and `aspectRatio: 1.333`, the height of the `<Video>` elements always stays the same. The `aspectRatio` prop is not respected.

Why is that so?

I want the video elements to fill the width of their parent, but their height should be set according to the `aspectRatio` prop.